# Заполнить QTableView данными через одну строку

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

Необходимо заполнить таблицу значениями из списка, **`через оду строку`**.

Я использовал для этого:

```
d_md = [(x, x) for i, x in enumerate(c)]  # (создавая дубликаты значений списка)
```

Затем заполняю каждую вторую строку в таблице:

```
for row in range(0, len(z), 2)
```

Есть более короткий вариант, решения вопроса?

Минимальный пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Класс QTableView")
window.resize(500, 400)
view = QtWidgets.QTableView()

model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(20, 10)
view.setModel(model)

c = [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10]

d_md = [(x, x) for i, x in enumerate(c)]  # вставка дубликатов в список
z = []
for i in d_md:
    for j in i:
        z.append(j)
 print(z)  # [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10]

for row in range(0, len(z), 2):  
for col in range(1, 2):
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(z[row]))
    model.setItem(row, col, item)


box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(view)
window.setLayout(box)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю зачем вам это надо, но предложу попробовать так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 10)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        
        c = [0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10]

        for row in range(len(c)):
            self.model.appendRow([
                QtGui.QStandardItem(""), 
                QtGui.QStandardItem(f"{c[row]}")
            ])
            self.model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem("")) 
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setWindowTitle("Класс QTableView")
    w.resize(500, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]